# How to ignore node_modules with node.js lambda and serverless frameowrk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am trying to deploy lambda function using node.js, as of now when i use `serverless deploy` my entire project directory is being pushed to lambda in a zip file.

But keeping in mind the scale of project, i am looking for something where node_modules are not included when i use `serverless deploy` and instead they get installed during deployment of lambda, in short something similar to serverless pligins for python https://www.tutorialspoint.com/serverless/serverless_plugins.htm

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with "get installed during deployment of lambda"? Because packaging `node_modules` in the deployment ZIP is absolutely what you should do. Only other option might be to use a Lambda Layer. But this would increase deployment complexity.

Comment: What i meant was if node_modules size increases with the number of dependencies with the size of project then deployment ZIP ( compressed which has a limitation of 50MB would reach) so i was thinking in a way that lambda should install node_modules on its end rather than me pushing the entire node_modules directory

Comment: That isn't how Lambda works. You need to provide all dependencies (besides the aws-sdk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The libraries in `node_modules` are required for your function to run in AWS Lambda. That's why they're called `dependencies`, and that's why they are zipped and uploaded to S3, because your function needs them in order to run.

If you're using specific libraries like typescript, joi, mocha, or jest which are only meant for development, you can ensure the Serverless framework will not package them by installing them as development dependencies, like this:

```
npm i -D joi
```

`serverless deploy` *is* the deployment of lambda. The `serverless-python-requirements` plugin is simply a packaging extension, that gives python projects a similar workflow as nodejs projects with npm.

The only package available to you by Lambda is the [aws-sdk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-package.html)

Comment: But what if node_modules size grows to a ver big number as project increases, is there a way where i ignore node_modules from my end and instruct lambda to install it automatically

Comment: That isn't how Lambda works. The only library AWS guarantees present by default in Lambda is the aws-sdk, everything else you need to provide. You may consider Lambda Layers, or using a docker image (which allows 10GB deployment packages vs 250mb Lambda allows via zip), but it's best to not let your packages grow that large. Use more than one lambda! You're billed by execution, not billed by number of functions.

Comment: You can look into tools like Webpack or esbuild to minize the size of your Lambdas code.